# Uniform random numbers are the same in all runs

Tags: c++, random

I find a method of generating uniform random number in range(aa,bb) as below:

```
#include <random>
double randnum (double aa, double bb)  //defining a function to create random numbers
{
  static std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution (aa,bb);
  return distribution(generator);
}
    int main (){
for (i=1;i<50;i++){
    cout<< randnum(0,1);
}
    }
```

For example, randnum(0,1); creates a random number between 0 and 1. The problem is that, during different runs, the random sequence which I create in for loop is exactly the same. How can I create different random numbers during different runs?

Comment: You recreate the generator each call, resetting the seed.

Comment: How can I avoid it? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: You need some external source of entropy, as the random engine is pesudo random

Comment: You need to randomly seed the generator when you construct it. Often people pass `std::random_device{}()` as an argument to the constructor.

Comment: You mean I should use this one? #include <random>
double randnum (double aa, double bb)  //defining a function to create random numbers
{
  static std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::random_device{}()
  return distribution(generator);
} @Galik

Comment: If I do as above comment, how can I tell the generator the interval of uniformly distributed random number? @Galik

Comment: Read the examples on cppreference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a non-deterministic random number engine to seed a more performant, deterministic one, like the mersenne twister:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

double randnum (double aa, double bb) { //defining a function to create random numbers
    static std::random_device rd; // non-deterministic, but may be slow
    static std::mt19937 engine{ rd() };
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution (aa,bb);
    return distribution(engine);
}

int main() {
    for(int i=1; i<50; i++) {
        std::cout<< randnum(0,1);
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/dgvarY